# Server side extjs form validation using zend framework

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, extjs, extjs4

Server side extjs form validation using zend framework

I have extended Zend_Form class to validate my client side extjs form:

```
  class Application_Form_NewBugReport extends Zend_Form {

public function init() {
    // Set the method for the display form to POST
    //here we go with different elements
    }}
```

Then added this code to my controller:

```
public function submitformAction() {

    // Instantiate the registration form model
    $form = new Application_Form_NewBugReport ();
    $form->setAction('/newbugreport/submitform');
    fb ( $form->getValues() );
    }
```

But values are empty and I can`t get form values because zend says form values are empty while they are not and I can get them using $this->_request->getPost ()  (and of course without any validations)
        What is the proper solution for validating forms when you don't actually use ZF forms and use client side javascript to create forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to validate the form against some input, in this case the POST data:

```
$form->setAction('/url');
if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
    fb($form->getValues());
}
```

Comment: Data are not validated because values are empty and I can`t get form values using getValues() because zend says form values are empty while they are not.

Comment: What kinds of validators do you have set on your form? It would be helpful to see the code for that.